# ASP.Net MVC3 Organising Content on Homepage View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Still a novice to asp.net and MVC3 I have been actively learning online for ways to do the things I used Classic ASP to achieve. Till now, I am able to do mono views  based on linq queries in a controller.  My problem is in a typical web application homepage where you are displaying different content originating from different queries how is that achieved in MVC3.  My question may sound silly but that is the only barrier i am facing now. Hitherto, with classic ASP I used include files to organise contents in my page.  I hear of partial views but am not sure if that is the way to go.  If you can help me give me an example of how I can display two views with different content in the home  page. eg main section display a view of recent comments from commentscontroller  and side section displays a view of recent news headlines from news controller. If you can point me to the right direction that will also be appreciated. I know I have a lot to learn on my own but at times some guide from an expert can save you weeks of own learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render different (unrelated) pieces of content using separate views you have two options in ASP.NET MVC:

1. RenderPartial
2. RenderAction

In the first case, we collect all data in a single action (e.g. `HomeController.Index()`), pass an aggregate view model object to the view, then call `RenderPartial` from the view, passing in the data:

```
<div id="comments">
  @Html.RenderPartial("Comments", Model.Comments)
</div>
<div>
  @Html.RenderPartial("News", Model.Headlines)
</div>
```

Notice here that the view model already contains all the data in `Model.Comments` and `Model.Headlines`, we are just passing it to a different partial view for rendering.

The downside of this approach is that the HomeController is doing the work to fetch latest comments **and** the latest news headlines. In object oriented code we generally want to separate such concerns. In this case we should separate the logic of fetching comments and news headlines.

In the second case, ASP.NET MVC provides us with an out-of-the-box solution which is to call `RenderAction(action, controller)` from the view. This will call on a **separate controller** to provide the output:

```
<div>
  @Html.RenderAction("Latest", "Comments")
</div>
<div>
  @Html.RenderAction("Headlines", "News")
</div>
```

Now we are calling on the `CommentsController` and `NewsController` respectively to render a partial view result. We have effectively separated the concern of fetching comments and news headlines into separate controllers. The `HomeController` no longer needs to provide the data to our homepage view.

For this to work, the actions that you call through RenderAction should ideally return a `PartialViewResult`:

```
public PartialViewResult Headlines( )
{
  string[] headlines = ...;
  return PartialView("Headlines", headlines);
}
```

Comment: thanks very much @michielvoo You can not imagine the number of hours you have saved my by your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better resource for learning the basics than http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/ it contains all code samples, instructions and good descriptions on how particular features work. You may be most interested in chapter 10 that covers Layout and PartialViews

Comment: Thanks @torm for the direction I will surely consult that link for the fill ins left to learn